# How to make an image full screen?

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble making my image fullscreen. if i make a  css: .background {background: url....} it works fine but then noting else works. So I made it as and image but the image isnt bigger in height than my screen so i have to scroll. Can anyone help me with this and maybe help to find other mistakes?

Thanks <3

(i see you cant see the picture were I am talking about but maybe you now the solution without seeing it :D)

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.centered {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.header {
    background-color: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    -moz-opacity: 0.80;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: 0.8;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
    padding-top: 102px;
}

.logo {
    Width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
    float: left;
}

#foto {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Duco's Blog </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<header>
    <div class="header" id="myHeader">
        <img class="logo" src="leeuw.png">
    </div>
    <script>
        window.onscroll = function() {
            myFunction()
        };

        var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
        var sticky = header.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
            if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
                header.classList.add("sticky");
            } else {
                header.classList.remove("sticky");
            }
        }

    </script>
</header>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="straat.jpg" alt="street" id="foto">
        <div class="centered">Centered</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While I don't know your user-base I feel relatively secure in saying that there's no need to be using `opacity` with vendor prefixes anymore. I'd also suggest that, unless you're targeting a *very* old version of IE that the use of `-ms-filter` is probably ripe to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `height: 100vh` to the `#foto` element. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You want to make your image a background image, not an inline image, e.g. use background properties instead of the `<img />` tag:

```
body {
  margin: 0;

  /* Fullscreen image */
  /* get the image source */
  background-image: url('/path/to/image.png');

  /* center it */
  background-position: center center;

  /* fix it to the window so it doesn't scroll */
  background-attachment: fixed;

  /* ensure it covers the whole screen */
  background-size: cover;
}
```

If that's your full site's HTML, it looks like you don't need the JavaScript to make your header stick to the top of the window. You can get what you need for your fixed header by just using CSS.

```
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

`position: fixed;` pulls your element out of the regular flow so you'll need to over-compensate for your header's height otherwise it'll cover some of your content:

```
.header-buffer {
  /* overcompensate for fixed header */
  padding-top: 60px; 
}
```

The class `.header-buffer` would be added to the element wrapping the content after the header.

Essentially:

- delete your image tag
- delete all CSS for `#foto`
- delete your JavaScript
- add the background properties to the body CSS
- add the `.header-buffer` class to the same element that has the `.container` class, e.g. `<div class="container header-buffer">...</div>`

Here's an example CodePen:

- Preview: https://codepen.io/tinacious/full/wRvKwy
- [source code](https://codepen.io/tinacious/pen/wRvKwy)

In the example you can see that the window can be any size and the image will take up the whole screen. The website content is also scrollable so you can see the header staying fixed to the top.